# When should we use the place_pruned_graph config?

Tags: tensorflow

Question:As the title saied, I wander When should we use the config place_pruned_graph in GraphOptions. What's the purpose of this config?

I'm not clear to the comment about this config:

```
  // Only place the subgraphs that are run, rather than the entire graph.
  //
  // This is useful for interactive graph building, where one might
  // produce graphs that cannot be placed during the debugging
  // process.  In particular, it allows the client to continue work in
  // a session after adding a node to a graph whose placement
  // constraints are unsatisfiable.
```

We know that Tensorflow will partition a entire graph into several subgraphs in normal. And [the following code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc#L1108) from CreateGraphs of direct_session.cc takes the else branch in normal.(as far as I can see, I never found the case taking the if branch(so I don't know when should we trigger it).

```
  if (options_.config.graph_options().place_pruned_graph()) {
    // Because we are placing pruned graphs, we need to create a
    // new SimpleGraphExecutionState for every new unseen graph,
    // and then place it.
    SimpleGraphExecutionStateOptions prune_options;
    prune_options.device_set = &device_set_;
    prune_options.session_options = &options_;
    prune_options.stateful_placements = stateful_placements_;
    TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(SimpleGraphExecutionState::MakeForPrunedGraph(
        execution_state_->original_graph_def().library(), prune_options,
        execution_state_->original_graph_def(), subgraph_options,
        &temp_exec_state_holder, &client_graph));
    execution_state = temp_exec_state_holder.get();
  } else {
    execution_state = execution_state_.get();
    TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(
        execution_state->BuildGraph(subgraph_options, &client_graph));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer? **Never.** The longer answer requires me to explain why this option exists at all.

So why does TensorFlow include this convoluted configuration option and logic to handle it? It's a historical accident that came about when `tensorflow::DirectSession` and `tensorflow::GrpcSession` had different internal implementations:

1. The `tensorflow::GrpcSession` used a single [`SimpleGraphExecutionState`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/012f9c10dcc27a838ed4b170b9036483bc2c5869/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_graph_execution_state.h) for the entire graph in a session. The net effect of this was that the placer—which is responsible for assigning devices to each node in the graph—would run **before** the graph was pruned.
2. The `tensorflow::DirectSession` originally used one `SimpleGraphExecutionState` for each pruned subgraph, with some special logic for sharing the placements of stateful nodes between invocations. Therefore the placer would run **after** the graph was pruned, and could make different decisions about where to place stateful nodes.

The benefit of the `tensorflow::GrpcSession` approach (`place_pruned_graph = false`) is that it takes into account all of the colocation constraints in the graph when running the placement algorithm, even if they don't occur in the subgraph being executed. For example, if you had an embedding matrix, and wanted to optimize it using the `SparseApplyAdagrad` op (which [only has a CPU implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/012f9c10dcc27a838ed4b170b9036483bc2c5869/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc#L1540)), TensorFlow would figure out that the embedding matrix should be placed on CPU.

By contrast, if you specified no device for the embedding matrix and set `placed_pruned_graph = true` the matrix would (most likely) be placed on GPU when you ran its `initializer`, because all of the ops in the initialization subgraph would be runnable on GPU. And, since variables cannot move between devices, TensorFlow would not be able to issue the subgraph that ran `SparseApplyAdagrad` on the matrix. This was a [real issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1297) in the earliest version of TensorFlow.

So why support `place_pruned_graph = true` at all? It turns out that it is useful when using TensorFlow interactively. The `placed_pruned_graph = false` option is unforgiving: once the graph for a session contains a node that cannot be placed, that session is useless, because the placement algorithm runs on the whole graph, it would fail every time it is invoked, and therefore no steps could run. When you use a [`tf.InteractiveSession`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/InteractiveSession), we assume that you are using a REPL (or Jupyter notebook) and that it's beneficial to allow you to continue after making such a mistake. Therefore in a `tf.InteractiveSession` we set `place_pruned_graph = true` so that you can continue to use the session after adding an unplaceable node (as long as you don't try to run that node in a pruned subgraph).

There is probably a better approach than `place_pruned_graph = true` for interactive use, but we haven't investigated adding one. Suggestions are always welcome on the [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).